# Autocomplete For Public/Shared Computer

Tags: html, security, browser, authentication, autocomplete

After sitting for hours on end with what, in my mind anyway is the simplest of requirements, I am giving up.
The need is that a shared computer browser will be used by various personnel to login, do what they need to, and log out again.

It is hence imperative that the user's details NEVER be populated into the user name and / or password fields.

I have tried scripts and attributes on the HTML from various stackoverflow threads... to no avail.  To make matters worse, even clearing ALL history for Firefox and Chrome does not clear previously entered values (how can this be?).  Note that in Chrome it autofills it and in Firefox I can see all previous logins by double clicking the user name box.

I do know... that when you change user that the browsers ask you whether you want for it to remember these details for you.

It is however important to note that the defaults for this in all major browsers are to "Remember!".  For hectic workplaces it is just so easy for a user to accept this without thinking about it (and sadly, these users are not browser experts but simply trying to do their job)...  leaving the user (and the system) at serious risk.  I also don't think that for these situations that it is the decision of the user - but from a systems point of view the developer should be able to limit it.

I find this behavior for browsers not only impossible for the implementation mentioned - and cannot believe there to be no programmatic answer to this?  I furthermore find this behaviour of the browser to be more distracting than helpful, even to myself as a more literate user.

If there is anybody there that has a technique that works...  then please share.

Comment: Also note...  I have no control over the settings of the browser from an installation point of view.  Neither do I have control over the browser being used.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly (some) recent versions of browsers seem to ignore even the autocomplete="off" tag due to the users comfort, but as your example shows there are situations that security matters are far more important than user comfort. Maybe this will be somewhat helpful to you (if using the jQ plugin is allowed in your case):

https://github.com/say2joe/jquery.disable-autocomplete

Comment: Thank you Roman!  Even the stubborn Chrome removed the value...  will continue testing - but so far so good.

Comment: OOPS!  There is a caveat to using it. Setting the input focus does not work anymore -         $('input[type=password]').disableAutocomplete();
        $('input[type=text]').disableAutocomplete();
        $('#userName').focus();

Comment: The focus function (and possibly tab function) won't work as simple as before due to the plugin "way of work". Read carefully how it works -> it creates 2 hidden copys of a field (you created) to avoid showing autocomplete hints. You must check the class/id/name of the field you see after running plugin, because what you actually see is not what you have created, you see only that mentioned copy of your field which (i'm not sure here) have some other class/id (which actually you should use to the focus selector).